# GKE Autopilot Session Affinity

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I'm looking to move some game servers I was running on VMs over to a GKE Autopilot deployment, and I'm trying to figure out how I can configure the Ingress component to route both players of the same game to the same Pod (i.e. I want a single public game URL that will route both players/any spectators over to the same backing pod that will have the game state in memory, given the game id in the path of the request or as a header/cookie). I'm still relatively new to Kubernetes, so I'm having trouble finding a good example/the magic Google search terms that would set me on the right path to solving this. [This](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity) seems to point out that HEADER_FIELD/HTTP_COOKIE are options I can specify, but I can't seem to find an example that demonstrates how this would work. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, regarding the header you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers) on how to create custom headers in backend services. Visit the "How custom headers work" and "Custom request headers".

About routing the players to the same pod I actually don't recommend this because of the [Pod Lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/pod#pod_lifecycle) there is a different path we can do for this concern, you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multi-cluster-ingress#ingress_concepts)

Comment: Thanks @YvanG! I'm not sure I understand how the MultiClusterIngress helps here. Is there an example you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding multicluster ingress, if your setup has a different cluster and you want a specific traffic or url to route to a specific pod then you can use multicluster ingress. About the sample you are requesting you can also see the sample diagram from the same [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multi-cluster-ingress#multiclusteringress_resource) under MultiClusterIngress Resource.

From the link, you will see, there are two example url (foo.example.com and bar.example.com) and how it will route these to a specific pod. Based on the sample diagram in the document. “In the diagram, there are two clusters, gke-eu and gke-asia. Traffic flows from foo.example.com to the Pods that have the label app:foo across both clusters. From bar.example.com, traffic flows to the Pods that have the label app:bar across both clusters.”

A sample yaml configuration is also available from the link I shared. Regarding your concern, the sample url can have the same concept of your public url so the player that will access your url will route to the specific pod that you like.